# asp.net - trigger updatepanel on pressing the return key

Tags: asp.net, triggers, updatepanel, keypress

I have a page with an updatepanel which contains a small login form - it runs fine when the user clicks on the submit button, but if the user presses the return key after entering their password, it does not run.

Here's the code...

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="loginButton" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="username" MaxLength="11" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="password" MaxLength="64" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="loginButton" OnClick="Submit_login" runat="server" Text="<img src='login.png' alt='Login' />" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add a panel in the Content template and assign the `DefaultButton`, it should submit the button when a user hits Enter.

```
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:panel id="p" runat="server" defaultbutton="loginButton">
            //Form here with loginButton
</asp:panel>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: This worked... however, I had to use an imageButton rather than a LinkButton to make it work as I would expect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put your the controls that are inside `<ContentTemplate>` inside an `Panel` and set it's default button to be loginButton.

Like this:

```
<asp:Panel id="defaultPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="loginButton">
  <asp:TextBox ID="username" MaxLength="11" runat="server" />
  <asp:TextBox ID="password" MaxLength="64" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
  <asp:LinkButton ID="loginButton" OnClick="Submit_login" runat="server" Text="<img src='login.png' alt='Login' />" />
</asp:Panel>
```